# How can I find a specific Product id by sending Product Name?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift2, firebase-realtime-database

I use Firebase For My Store App. I want to find a Product's Details by taking a product name for the user. My JSON format looks like this:

```
 {
product :
 electronic = 
      a  = {
             pname = "iphone 5"
              pprice = "20000"
              pdescription = "Details....."  }
       b = {
           pname = "iphone  6"
              pprice = "30000"
              pdescription = "Details....."  }

 }
 cloths = 
       a =    pname = "shirt"
              pprice = "200"
              pdescription = "Details....."  }
       b = {
           pname = "pents"
              pprice = "300"
              pdescription = "Details....."  }

}
```

Now, suppose I have the name `iphone 5`, then how can I find out the other details of the product?

Answer (score 0):

```swift
import Firebase
FIRApp.configure()
ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

let prod_query = "iphone 5"

ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

  let product_enum = snapshot.children
  while let product = product_enum.nextObject() as? FDataSnapshot {

    product.queryEqualToValue(child:"\(prod_query)").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snap) in

      let pid = snap.key as! String
      let pprice = snap.value!["pprice"] as! Int
      let pdescription = snap.value!["pdescription"] as! String

    })

  }

})
```

<s>This implies that you know what the product letter is so that you can pull the correct name, price, and description.</s>
The while loop will iterate through the different types of products (electronics, cloths, etc) and perform a query searching for a product ID that contains the child with the `pname` you're looking for.

Firebase suggests that instead of using `.Value`, it's better to use `.ChildAdded` since it accomplishes the same goal while managing new objects added.  But since it appears you are trying to view static data, `.Value` works just fine.

This should serve as an excellent example as to how you can retrieve data using Firebase.  But I suggest [checking](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/interface_f_i_r_database_reference) out the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/retrieve-data) on your own just in case you have further questions.

While I really don't mind looking this information up... this site is used in order to gain a better understanding of code, rather than existing as a collection of personal assistants.

Showing research efforts within your question can go a long way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
 FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("product/electronic").queryOrderedByChild("pname").queryEqualToValue("iphone 5").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value , withBlock : {(snap) in 

     if let snapDict = snap.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
         for each in snapDict{
            print(each.0) // product key
            print(each.1) //product details
        }
       }

   })
```